# Using field and property to construct getter and setter in C#

Tags: c#

For the following code, I don't quiet understand what is the meaning of "{0}" presented in both getter and setter, I know it is referring to a index number but why it should be 0 ? I'm also confused about the variable "value". Is this just a place parameter like we used in Java ?

Thank you.

```
void Main() {
Button b = new Button();  
b.Caption = "abc";
string c = b.Caption; 
Console.WriteLine("c = {0}\r\n", c);

Button p = new Button{Caption = "cool"};    
string e = p.Caption;
Console.WriteLine("e = {0}", e);
}

class Button {
    private string caption;
    public string Caption {
        get {
            Console.WriteLine("get {0}", caption);
            return caption;
 }
    set {
        Console.WriteLine("set {0}", value);
        caption = value;
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: Format placeholder.

Comment: [This is documented on MSDN, as you might expect.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/828t9b9h(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: The variable `value` is the parameter of the setter. In Java, you would write it as a method parameter: `public void setCaption(String value) {...}`

Comment: The `value` variable always contains the setter value. In this case, if you do `Caption = "test"`, value would be `test`

Comment: [The `value` keyword is also documented on MSDN.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1khb4f8.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a format placeholder, the actual method `Console.WriteLine()` allows you to use the same syntax as `String.Format()`.

The placeholders represent the numeric indice of the parameters supplied after the format string.

For example:

```
var s = String.Format("Hello {0}!", "World");
```

Would print:

```
Hello World!
```

An example of multiple placeholders would be:

```
var s = String.Format("{0} Blind {1}", "Three", "Mice");
```

You can also then use various other formatting specifiers to finer control the output of the value. It's quite a broad topic so see [here on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd(v=vs.110).aspx) for more information on Composite Formatting.

As to `value` that's a contextual keyword, i.e it only exists within certain contexts, in your case properties.

`value` acts in this instance as a variable of the property type filled with the value of the property being set.

You can read more about contextual keywords again on MSDN [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/the35c6y.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

{0}, means take the 1st of the objects specified after the format string

{1}, means take the 2nd of the objects specified after the format string
etc

...in other words...the index is zero based.

The "value" keyword is a "contextual keyword" is it a placeholder to represent the actual value "set" to the property (when used in a propert setter).

(there are other ones available in case you are interested: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/the35c6y.aspx)